# Make Columns Change from 6 to 4 to 2 Based on Screen Size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns, screen-size

Currently I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5 CSS on a ***NSFW*** video hosting site. On the front page, if the screen size has a width of 1200px and greater, there are 12 videos displayed in 6 columns of 2. When the screen width gets below 768px, those 6 columns change into 2 columns to better fit the screen.

What I want to add is CSS where if the screen is smaller than 1200px but greater than 768px, 4 columns will display.

**Below is a link to the video showing how everything changes based on screen size:**

This video is ***NSFW*** 
http://tinypic.com/r/fuosw3/9

As you can see, as the screen gets smaller the thumbnails get smaller but it remains 6 columns all the way down to when the size is less than 768px and it changes into 2.

What CSS can I use to have it switch to 4 columns after going under 1200px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the @media property of css as follow:

That will be applied for screen with width < 1200px

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    <do your stuff>
}
```

That will be applied only for screens with width > 768px

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        <do your stuff>
}
```